# Woocommerce payment gateway webhook doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I will be very grateful for any help. I'm trying to create a custom payment gateway for WooCommerce. The problem is in the callback function, I cannot process the response from the payment system. I set up payment, everything works fine, but I can’t get a response from payment system and complete the order on my site. Please, help

```
<?php

        public function generate_form($order_id)
        {
            //GET MERCHANT ID FROM SETTINGS
            $merch_id = $this -> merchant_id;
            
            // GET ORDER
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

            // GET AMMOUNT
            $sum = $order->get_total();

            // format the amount
            $sum = number_format($sum, 0, '.', '');
            
            // GET CURRENCY
            $currency = $this->currency_type;
            
            // GET SECRET KEY FROM SETTINGS
            $secretKey = $this->merchant_secretkey;

            $description = sprintf(__('Payment for Order #%1$s', 'payme'), $order_id);

            $label_pay = __('Pay', 'payme');
            $label_cancel = __('Cancel payment and return back', 'payme');
            
            // Generating a digital signature in PHP (EXAMPLE FROM PAYMENT SYSTEM DOCS)
            function getFormSignature($merch_id, $currency, $sum, $order_id, $secretKey) {
             $hashStr = $merch_id.'{up}'.$currency.'{up}'.$sum.'{up}'.$order_id.'{up}'.$secretKey;
             return hash('sha256', $hashStr);
            }
            
            $signature = getFormSignature($merch_id, $currency, $sum, $order_id, $secretKey);


            $form = <<<FORM
<form action="{$this->checkout_url}" method="get">
    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" value="$sum" />
    <input id="act "name="act" type="hidden" value="request_payment" />
    <input id="test" name="test" type="hidden" value="{$this->test_mode}" />
    <input id="form" name="form" type="hidden" value="Y" />
    <input id="coin" name="coin" type="hidden" value="{$this->coin_type}" />
    <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="$merch_id" />
    <input id="currency" name="currency" type="hidden" value="$currency" />
    <input id="external_invoice" name="external_invoice" type="hidden" value="$order_id" />
    <input id="message" name="message" type="hidden" value="$description" />
    <input id="signature" name="signature" type="hidden" value="$signature" />
    <input type="submit" class="button alt" id="submit_payme_form" value="$label_pay">
    <a class="button cancel" href="{$order->get_cancel_order_url()}">$label_cancel</a>
</form>
FORM;

            return $form;
        }

        public function process_payment($order_id)
        {
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

            return [
                'result' => 'success',
                'redirect' => add_query_arg(
                    'order_pay',
                    $order->get_id(),
                    add_query_arg('key', $order->get_order_key(), $order->get_checkout_payment_url(true))
                )
            ];

        }
        
        public function receipt_page($order_id)
        {
            echo '<p>' . __('Thank you for your order, press "Pay" button to continue.', 'payme') . '</p>';
            echo $this->generate_form($order_id);
        }


        /**
         * CALLBACK FUNCTION. THE REQUESTS SENT FROM PAYMENT SYSTEM TO MY CALLBACK URL https://example.com/?wc-api=wc_custom
         */
        public function custom_webhook()
        {
            
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
            
            $id = $this -> merchant_id;
            $currency = $this->currency_type;
            $secretKey = $this->merchant_secretkey;
            $amount_in_currency = $order->get_total();

            /** 
            * INSTRUCTION FROM DOCS: 
            * When we receive an invoice payment, we notify the merchant website of the payment status by sending a GET request to the handler URL (callback_url parameter).
            * In the payment processor, you must generate a digital signature using the received variables and check it against the received digital signature.
            */
            
            // CODE EXAMPLE FORM DOCS. An example of generating and verifying a digital signature in PHP  
            
            function getSignature($id, $currency, $amount_in_currency, $order_id, $secretKey) {
             $hashStr = $id.'{up}'.$currency.'{up}'.$amount_in_currency.'{up}'.$order_id.'{up}'.$secretKey;
             return hash('sha256', $hashStr);
            }

            $signature = getSignature($_GET["id"], $_GET["currency"], $_GET["amount_in_currency"], $_GET["external_invoice"], $secretKey);
            
            if ($_GET["signature"] != $signature){
                $order->payment_complete();
                WC()->cart->empty_cart();
            }
                exit('Incorrect Digital Signature');
                
            // ERROR. WEBHOOK RESPONSE: Response - HTTP CODE: 400 DATA: -1 
        }

?>
```

I am getting a 400 response error and cannot process the order on the site. What should I do please help!(

Comment: This seems like you are mixing `methods` (functions within a Class) and a normal functions. Is there a Class that these appear in? Also, it looks like you have a function (getFormSignature) within your `generate_form` method.

Comment: I wrote a getFormSignature function inside process_payment() to get the values for the variables. I can't get the values of variables from outside. I'm just learning php and don't know code well, sorry. Please tell me where I can find a detailed guide on building payment gateways for Woo?

Comment: While I commend your effort, if you are just learning PHP, I would highly suggest not trying to connect to a payment gateway as a learning project. There isn't one specific guide on building a payment gateway for Woocommerce - it depends on the payment processor. You may consider hiring a more seasoned developer to handle this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).